# Checking the width and height of an already stored image (in a variable) in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Yo, im just trying to make this work. I would like to recieve the height and weidth of an image i donwloaded from database and already stored in a variable $image. For some reason the code doesnt work... using php7

here is the codde:

```
function displayImage($id){
    $query = "SELECT pic FROM desk WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'],$query);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($resultCheck>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $image = base64_encode($row['pic']);
            $imageW = imagesx($image);
            $imageH = imagesy($image);
            if($imageW>$imageH){
                return '<img align="center" height=50% width=auto src="data:image;base64,'.$image.'">';
            }else if($imageW<$imageH){
                return '<img align="center" height=auto width=50% src="data:image;base64,'.$image .'">';
            }else if($imageW===$imageH){
                return '<img align="center" height=50% width=50% src="data:image;base64,'.$image .'">';
            }

        }
    }
}
```

thanks to anyone who helps :)

Comment: You need to use imagecreatefromstring(   [image string] ), to put the image resource for use with imagesy

Comment: Those functions refer to PHP GD library created image, not just the image encoded into text

Comment: As an aside note: never store images in database; much better to put a reference to the physical file in a string.

Comment: The example on the PHP.net page is pretty useless as you already know the width and height of the image when creating an image for GD library. Temporary save your image to the files system and use `list($width, $height) = getimagesize('path to image');` to determine the correct dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the image as a String first, then encode it since the image width and height can be obtained from the decoded String. Take a look at the following code:

```
function displayImage($id){
    $query = "SELECT pic FROM desk WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'],$query);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($resultCheck>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $image = $row['pic'];
            $b64 = base64_encode($image);
            $dimen = getimagesizefromstring($image);
            $imageW = dimen[0];
            $imageH = dimen[1];
            if($imageW>$imageH){
                return '<img align="center" height=50% width=auto src="data:image;base64,'.$b64.'">';
            }else if($imageW<$imageH){
                return '<img align="center" height=auto width=50% src="data:image;base64,'.$b64 .'">';
            }else if($imageW===$imageH){
                return '<img align="center" height=50% width=50% src="data:image;base64,'.$b64 .'">';
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is very slow, if it's a problem for you then use this alternative: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php#94178 for retrieving dimensions from an image string as opposed to file.

Comment: @pokeybit I don't see why this is slow. I am not creating a string from an image, the string already exists. This shouldn't be any slower than what you have posted from what I understand.

Comment: getimagesizefromstring() is slow, just sayin :)

Comment: works ok :) thanks

Comment: @GašperBožič You're most welcome :)

Comment: @pokeybit Did not know this. Good to know.